# Speeding up shared memory operations c++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, boost, shared-memory, interprocess

I have a `dll` application which is written in `Visual Studio 2008 VC++`. Basicly it has two interface to the external applications.

One of them is for writer:

```
class writer_interface
{
    virtual void write (myData data, unsigned long id) = 0;
}
```

and the other one is for the reader apps:

```
class reader_interface
{
    virtual select(unsigned long id) = 0;
    virtual select(time_t insertionTime) = 0;
}
```

so I keep my meta data in an container in shared memory which I am using `boost managed_shared_memory`.

The problem is the external writer application call my write function like 15 times in a second and the readers make query on my shared memory container like 5 times in one second simultaneously.

So for each Write function call for my Write method I have to open shared memory & find my container like that:

```
//Open the managed segment
managed_shared_memory segment(open_only, "MySharedMemory");
//Find the vector using the c-string name
MyVector *myvector = segment.find<MyVector>("MyVector").first;
```

but this one is too costly where I have that frequent data. Because each opening shared memory & finding the container in it operation takes almost `100 milliseconds`. It means that there is a bottleneck because of that shared memory operations.

Same bottleneck situation occurs for reader apps as well.

My question is how can I make these shared memory operations faster? 
Is there a way to prevent opening and re-finding the container every time in shared memory?

Thank you.

Comment: Can't you cache the result of find as well as the segment object?

Comment: I tried to assign it as a class property like a variable or smth but it loses its value everytime it re-enters the class. What kind of caching you mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To cache lately opened segments in memory is a good idea. Suppose that you will cache last 10 opened segments. Create a singleton class that will hold a dictionary that maps string to segment object. Each time you need to read/write from any segment you will check if this singleton includes it already (by some id - its name for example). If yes - you will get its reference/pointer and read/write to it. Otherwise, you will open a new segment and store it in this singleton.

Singleton is a class that may have only one instance, usually created on first usage. See next link http://forums.codeguru.com/showthread.php?423850-how-to-implement-a-singleton-in-c-c.
I would do it like this.

In header file:

```
class Singleton {
public:
  static Singleton* instance();
  void write (myData data, unsigned long id);
  void select(unsigned long id);
  void select(time_t insertionTime);

private:
  Singleton();
  static Singleton* m_singleton;        // singleton instance
  managed_shared_memory m_segment;
};
```

In cpp file:
    Singleton* Singleton::m_singleton= NULL;

```
Singleton::Singleton()
: segment(open_only, "MySharedMemory")
{
   // do init stuff
}

Singleton* Singleton::instance()
{
  if (m_singleton== NULL)
    m_singleton = new Singleton();
  return m_singleton;
}

void Singleton::write (myData data, unsigned long id)
{
  //Find the vector using the c-string name
  MyVector *myvector = m_segment.find<MyVector>("MyVector").first;

  // add code here
}

void Singleton::select(unsigned long id)
{
// your code here
}

void Singleton::select(time_t insertionTime)
{
// your code here
}
```

Usage in the implementor of write_interface:

```
Singleton::instance().write (data, id);
```

The solution only ensures one instance since program starts until it ends.

Comment: Actually in my code it is also singleton but may be i'm doing smth wrong. I will try your way tomorrow and inform here. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Yeap the key part is: ":segment (open_only ..." thanks indeed.

Answer (score 0):

To cache lately opened segments in memory is a good idea.
Suppose that you will cache last 10 opened segments.
Create a singleton class that will hold a dictionary that maps string to segment object.
Each time you need to read/write from any segment you will check if this singleton includes it already (by some id - its name for example). If yes - you will get its reference/pointer and read/write to it. Otherwise, you will open a new segment and store it in this singleton.

Comment: Actually I should have only two segments. One segment is for the writer app (there is only one writer) the other segment is for reader apps (they should share the same segment) But I lose the segment whenever the program quits from the related method. I mean its scope seems like a local variable which is created in a method. I try to make the segment global by adding it as a property to the class but it didn't work. How to keep the segments as singleton?

Comment: In my example I used only one segment, but you can use 2 if you wish